# Is it possible for timer running in iOS background?

Tags: ios, timer, background

I made a timer. After I hit home button in iOs simulator, it was still running in the background. I didn't save the state, I only added local notification.  Why is that?

Also, I set to play a 4 seconds sound in notification and it came out that the sound only played 3 seconds. Is there a limitation of how long the sound can play for notification?

Comment: fixed typo, add punctuation mark

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you selected one of them:

[image]

Comment: I didn't ..I am very sure..I used to selected first and 2nd.but I deselected..But thanks